# Did Windows 11 remove the Shell sub-key under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon?

Tags: windows, shell, windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-11

Context: I was trying to add an application to the **Winlogon** Shell sub-key so that it starts loading along with the GUI on startup. It works fine, but I had to create the Shell sub-key and add **"explorer.exe , (app.exe)"**. After doing that, everything worked as expected but I noticed a small delay and auto-refresh at the Windows 11 lock screen, which prompted me to understand that "explorer.exe" was being executed twice. So I deleted the Shell key and everything is back to normal but with the obvious delay introduced by Windows 8 in starting applications after start-up. It is of concern to me because the application I was trying to run is a UX tweak and needs to be run at the same time as the GUI. So my question is which registry key is being used to run explorer.exe in the absence of the Shell key?

Comment: I do not have this Key on a Native Windows 11 Pro system. Also Windows 11 File Explorer is a different tool than a Windows 10 File Explorer.. Microsoft has been busy removing Registry changes in Windows 11.

Comment: @John - While there have been changes to File Explorer I would be absolutely shocked if they changed how an application is automatically started. As an experienced programmer I would look at the current Classic Shell project (whatever it’s new project name is) to understand the proper way to do a UX tweak.

Comment: @Ramhound I am just trying to load [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net) along with the GUI and this is apparently the only way to properly execute it.

Comment: Okay, so the Shell key is under HKLM and not HKCU. Still, didn't solve the delay issue.